How to get commit hash of current Jenkinsfile without checkout?
Either when creating a new plugin or just using groovy in the pipeline, how to get the commit hash of the Jenkinsfile. The commit hash is visible in the logs without using any kind of checkout or command. Example:
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 6d24a57f9359fe4a503dbc00179393a3eddd30c3

This makes me think there is a way, at least from a custom plugin, that this commit_hash can be obtained.
Tried:

env.GIT_COMMIT in node() block
Looking around in other plugins, how they do it
Looking through the Java docs of the Run

